# How to show flash messages in bootstrap modal window?

Tags: javascript, flask, bootstrap-4

Here is the problem. I have a bootstrap modal window with forms where i show up error messages with flask.flash() if any happend. But! When I click upload for the first time my modal window is closing, and I can see the error message only when I reopen the modal window. So the error message should show up when I click `Upload` button without closing the modal window, if the error happend, but if there is no errors, it should work as it is. How to make it behave the way I want? Is it js stuff? (which I don't know) Or it could be made by flask and bootstrap? Anyway, need your help guys.

[image: Upload form]
[image: Upload form with error message]

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('index') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
                        {% if messages %}
                            {% for category, message in messages %}
                            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                               {{ message }}
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endwith %}

                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type=file name=dump_file class="file-input" id="custom-file-input" multiple>
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="custom-file-input" data-browse="Browse">Choose file</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="linux">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">Linux</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="windows">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">Windows</label>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> -->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Upload</button>
                </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I was stuck with this too. There is a easy solution with JQuery:
This code basically opens up the modal only if the error (flash warning exist)

where .flash is the div that you named for your flash warning and

## changePasswordModal is the modal ID

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { // When page finished loading
  if ( $('.flash').length ) { // if there is an DOM that has class has-error
     $('#changePasswordModal').modal('show'); // Show Modal
  }
});
</script>
```